# Nesting OR in Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, boost-regex, boost-xpressive

How do I match an expression where I need to do an `or` of another set?

i.e., how do I match something of the format

```
[
  [
    [ a | b ] |
    [ x | y ]
  ]
]
```

where a, b, x and y are strings.

I want to match the phrases like

```
a
b
x
y
a x
a y
b x
b y
x a
x b
y a
y b
```

But not the ones like:

```
a b
x y
z z
```

I'm trying to use it in *Boost Xpressive* so I have the option to use either ECMAScript or Perl type regular expressions.

Comment: So you want to match a, b, x, y, ax, ay, bx, by?

Comment: This is a bit trickier than it seems...

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, Perl or JS or Boost will be good.

Comment: You sure you want `yb` instead of `by`? Or both?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté a, b, x, y, a x, a y, b x, b y, x a, x b, y a , y b. Please note the space between a and x.

Comment: @nhahtdh both. I want to match a, b, x, y, a x, a y, b x, b y, x a, x b, y a , y b.

Comment: As the complexity of the answers indicates, you are getting close to the limits of what regular expressions can usefully do for you.  You may be better served by building a real parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[ab] [xy]|[xy] [ab]|[abxy]
```

There are 3 choices here:

- Only `a`, `b`, `x`, `y` (single character)
- Or 2 character, `a` or `b` comes before `x` or `y`, space in between.
- Or 2 character, `x` or `y` comes before `a` or `b`, space in between.

I put `[abxy]` behind, just in case when you search, it will search for those in front (the paired up ones) before searching for the single ones. The order is important if you use the regex to search, but it doesn't matter much when you do validation.

Another way to write it:

```
[ab]( [xy])?|[xy]( [ab])?
```

That only works for character, but you can make it works for string. For example, let's say you have 4 strings `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`:

```
(s1|s2)( (s3|s4))?|(s3|s4)( (s1|s2))?
```

It searches for:

- Either `s1` or `s2`, may or may not (0 or 1 instance of) followed by `s3` or `s4`
- (The other way around)

This covers all the cases of `s1`, `s2`, etc. (single string), `s2 s3`, `s3 s2`, etc. (paired up, can reverse the order). The regex above will search for the longer version (paired up) before resorting to the single string, due to the default *greedy* property of quantifiers.

Note that I am using *capturing groups* `(pattern)` in the regex above, which will record the position of the string that matches the `pattern` inside. You can make them non-capturing group `(?:pattern)`, if you don't need to refer to the text that matches the pattern. This will save you some clock cycles.

```
(?:s1|s2)(?: (?:s3|s4))?|(?:s3|s4)(?: (?:s1|s2))?
```

(I leave the task of changing *capturing group* to *non-capturing group* for the other regex as an exercise. It is as simple as adding `?:`)

**Searching or Validation?**

If you want to find such pattern, then the regex above should work for you.

If you want to validate that the string matches the pattern, you need to use anchors `^` (match beginning of string), `$` (match the end of the string) to make sure the string follows the exact format:

```
^([ab] [xy]|[xy] [ab]|[abxy])$
^([ab]( [xy])?|[xy]( [ab])?)$
^((s1|s2)( (s3|s4))?|(s3|s4)( (s1|s2))?)$
^(?:(?:s1|s2)(?: (?:s3|s4))?|(?:s3|s4)(?: (?:s1|s2))?)$
```

Note that I surround the regex from the above sections with `()` (*capturing group*, but I only need *grouping* here actually). This is because I have an alternation `|` inside.

**Extensibility and Limitations**

- You can add more strings to either the first group or second group as you like:

  ```
  ^([abcd]( [xyz])?|[xyz]( [abcd])?)$
  ```
- However, if you want to increase the number of groups, I suggest that you split the string by spaces and loop through the tokens to find the permutations of the group, rather than using regex.

Comment: Note that this works for single characters. I believe OP would use `a`, `b` and such to denote strings as the question implies "I want to match the strings like".

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: OK... Will edit...

Comment: +1, looks like this will work nicely.

Comment: Why the double groups on `( (s3|s4))?`?

Comment: @Cerbrus To group the space making it optional together with the second alternation group.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just put the space in the inner group. Both work, I guess :P

Comment: instead of "[ab] [xy]|[xy] [ab]|[abxy]", try "[ab]( [xy])?|[xy]( [ab])?". Also, though the opp hasn't mentioned it, he may need the whole string to be matched.

Comment: @SEoF: It can be used for searching or validation - not sure what OP wants. And yes, that's another way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a convenient way to do this without repeating `a`, `b`, `x` and `y` in the regular expression, but this problem can be alleviated by building the expression from pre-declared sub-expressions.

This code demonstrates. Note that the first three lines of the `DATA` are invalid, and they aren't reproduced in the output.

```
use v5.10;
use warnings;

my $ab = qr/a|b/;
my $xy = qr/x|y/;

my $re = qr/^
(?:
  $ab (?: \s+ $xy)? | $xy (?: \s+ $ab)?
)
$/x;

while (<DATA>) {
  print if /$re/;
}


__DATA__
a b
x y
z z
a
b
x
y
a x
a y
b x
b y
x a
x b
y a 
y b
```

**output**

```
a
b
x
y
a x
a y
b x
b y
x a
x b
y b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^((a|b)( x| y)?|(x|y)( a| b)?)$
```

Anatomy of the regex:

```
# ^            - Line start
# (            - Group start
# (a|b)( x| y) - Match A or B followed by X or Y
# ?            - Where (X|Y) is optional
# |            - Or
# (x|y)( a| b) - Match X or Y followed by A or B
# ?            - Where (A|B) is optional
# )            - And group
# $            - End of line.
```

This matches:

```
a    y
b    a x
x    y b
```

But not:

```
a b
x y
z z
```

Comment: Alternation is associative, so `((a|b)|(x|y))` is identical to `a|b|x|y` apart from the captures.

Comment: @Borodin: edited my answer. Could you please remove the downvote if it's yours?

Comment: I'd suggest you change this one to using "[ab]" instead of "(a|b)" and the same goes for "(x|y)"

Comment: @SEoF: From the question: `where a, b, x and y are strings.`. Hence the `(|)`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. "^((a|b)( (x|y))?|(x|y)( (a|b))?)$" will separate out the spaces from the strings, and then you can add "?:" to the open parenthesis before the spaces should you need to pull out the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
(a|b|x|y|((a|b) (x|y))|((x|y) (a|b)))
```